# Is there any open source options for Database Virtualization?

Tags: database, virtualization, data-virtualization

Is it possible to list out any open-source options for database virtualization.
Wiki on database vitualization: [Database Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_virtualization)

Some of the proprietary options are as follows:

- [Delphix](https://www.delphix.com/blog/data-virtualization/what-delphix)
- VMWare vFabric Data Director
- NetApp FlexClone
- Actifio copy data virtualization
- EMC XtremIO

One of the product about which I can say about is Delphix.
Through Delphix we can create Virtual databases (VDB) by using it's thin client database provisioning and use that VDB to test your code or do other jobs.

I am looking for an open-source alternative through which VDBs can be provisioned.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at teiid

http://teiid.jboss.org/about/

You use eclipse to connect to the server component and manage it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to building out a solution, you can move you're Database to ZFS and accomplish the same as you would on Xtremio. You would snapshot the virtual volume responsible for your database and rebuild accordingly. I'm sure the automation exists somewhere.

This is a article I ran into to help get you started:
http://labs.qandidate.com/blog/2014/08/25/using-zfs-to-snapshot-your-database/

You can probably grow the solution to something that will work for regular use.